# RabbitMQ no ack in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, coffeescript, rabbitmq

I'm trying to get acknowledges of delivered and processed messages using RabbitMQ. Unfortunately no success.

Look at my simplified code:

**Server:**

```
  amqp = require("amqp")

  # Open a connection
  conn = amqp.createConnection( {url: "amqp://localhost"} , {reconnect: false})

  conn.on "ready", ->
    console.log "Conn Ready"

    conn.queue "queueX", {ack:true}, (queue) ->
      console.log "Subscribed #{queue.name}"

      # subscribe to that queue
      queue.subscribe { ack: true }, (message, headers, deliveryInfo, ack) ->
        console.log message
        queue.shift() if queue.shift?
```

**Client:**

```
  amqp = require("amqp")

  # Open a connection
  conn = amqp.createConnection( url: "amqp://localhost" , reconnect: false)

  conn.on "ready", ->
      console.log "Conn Ready"

      # declare the default exchange
      conn.exchange "exchX", {confirm:true, type:"fanout", autoDelete:true}, (exchange) ->

        # create a queue
        conn.queue "queueX", (queue) ->
          console.log "Subscribed #{queue.name}"

          queue.bind exchange, queue.name, ->

            # publish a message
            console.log "Sending  CloudAMQP 1"
            exchange.publish "", body:"Hello CloudAMQP 1", {}, (out1)->
              console.log "Callback called for msg CloudAMQP 1. Delivered: #{out1}"

            # publish a message
            console.log "Sending  CloudAMQP 2"
            exchange.publish "", body:"Hello CloudAMQP 2", {}, (out1)->
              console.log "Callback called for msg  CloudAMQP 2. Delivered: #{out1}"
```

**Server Output:**

```
Conn Ready
Subscribed queueX
{ body: 'Hello CloudAMQP 1' }
{ body: 'Hello CloudAMQP 2' }
```

**Client Output:**

```
Conn Ready
Subscribed queueX
Sending  CloudAMQP 1
Sending  CloudAMQP 2
Callback called for msg CloudAMQP 1. Delivered: false
Callback called for msg  CloudAMQP 2. Delivered: false
```

As you can see *Delivered* is false. Any idea what's wrong with this code?

Answer (score 1):

This is the way you confirm (acknowledge) the publish

```
exchange.publish('', {body: 'your body'}, {}, function(err){
  if (err) return console.error(err);

  console.info('published');
}).addListener('ack', function() {
  console.info('ack received');
});
```

PS: I do not use coffeescript so, excuse me for posting normal javascript :), it's hard for me to convert, if you are having trouble with this I will give it a shot

Comment: I'm affraid it's not working as well. No matter if there was a client or not the results is exactly the same. Maybe I don't understand what can be confirmed. Can I get confirmation that acutually someone consumed my message or I'm getting confirmation that rabbit enqueued it?

Comment: When you exchange.publish() you will get confirmation that you have successfully published the message to an exchange, you do not know if that message went to a queue, there was a flag 'immediate' which was removed (http://www.rabbitmq.com/blog/2012/11/19/breaking-things-with-rabbitmq-3-0/) and there is a 'mandatory' flag that let's you reroute messages that did not ended up in a queue, but it's not the publisher's job to decide what to do with a message. After the message is inside a queue you have the possibility to confirm if messages was consumed successfully before being removed from it.

Comment: When you build up your rmq you control what needs to exists 'forever' and what not, you make your exchange & queue durable and they will be created even after a restart. It can happen that a queue is busy, and it's handling other tasks at the moment when you publish a 'new' message, if you wait for it to send you consumed confirmation is not a good practice. The Publisher needs just to know that his message was received by an exchange, and that's it, he did his job. Maybe in your case any simple/small pub/sub solution is better, you do not need a rmq server for that.